# Triggering the file upload input element does not work with Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have some code where I intercept the click event on a file upload input element. It works pretty well with Internet Explorer but not with Google Chrome.

**Why do I intercept the click event?** Because I need to be sure the user saved any changes before browsing to select any files to upload. In the case of need to save, I call the save function (which return a promise) then I trigger the same file input element again.

The html:

```
<input type="file" name="files[]" data-bind="click: $root.fileUploadClick">
```

The javascript:

```
var fileUploadClick = function (data, event) {

    if (hasChanges()) {
        var promise = Q.all([save()]);
        return promise.then(success);
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
    function success() {
        var tgt = event.currentTarget;
        $(tgt).click();
    };
};
```

With Google Chrome, when I debug I can clearly see that the click element is triggered the first time, the call to save is done, then re-trigger the click with `$(tgt).click()` then the browse window is not displayed.

PS: it works with all browsers if `hasChanges()` return false. In this case the browse window is displayed correctly.

Any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: you can't spoof a file upload click for security and annoyance reasons. just run the save in the background and have your onchange callback wait for the save to complete before continuing.

Comment: You are right, I'll proceed like you suggested. Thanks.